# Select columns from excel file by using C#

Tags: c#, excel, adapter

for the query:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from[" + sheetName + "$] where [BARKOD] is not null", Connection);
```

can I get the data of specific columns for example column 1(header=ID) and 3(header=NAME) instead of whole table(*)?

Comment: Are you aware of these projects? http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/, http://xlslinq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could select the column name first, for example:

```
DataTable schemaColTable = Connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null);
String firstColumnName = schemaColTable.Select(null, "TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
```

Then you use these column names for your queries.